# Grails : Use value from session in drop down list option

Tags: grails, gsp

In my controller:

```
def billingDetails() {
    def traineeDetails = session.traineeDetais
    println "session data::"+traineeDetails 

    [traineeNames:traineeDetails.name]
}
```

This prints: `[numberOfTrainees:2, submit_trainee_details:Next: Billing Details ∩┐╜, phone:[999999, 99999], email:[tester1@test.com, tester2@test.com], name:[Jack, Rob], jobTitle:[SE, SE], action:processTraineeDetails, controller:trainingOrder]`

now in my GSP i want to have a select tag which will have name (jack, Rob) as options

```
  <g:select name="traineeName"
      from="${traineeNames}"
      value=""
      />
```

which is not working fine.. How to make this to work so that i will get the names as options in dropdown list

Answer (score 0):

make use of the optionKey optionValue fields in your g:select

reference:
http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Tags/select.html

and do something like

```
<g:select optionKey="value" optionValue="value"
          name="traineeName" from="${traineeNames}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact problem but one possible reason is that your  `session.traineeDetais.name` is not a list. Check weather `session.traineeDetais.name` is a list or not, like

```
println "Check: ${session.traineeDetais.name instanceof List}"
```

if it is list then your code should work and if it is string then your drop down contain string characters as values.